# In Twitter, how can I search the hash tags related to a particular region?

Tags: twitter, search

In Twitter, how can I search the hash tags related to a particular region?

Like #trends in New York.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
#trends near:"New York" within:5mi
```

`5mi` = 5 mile. Defines the radius to search around New York.

Comment: No problem. If that answered your query, you can mark it as answer. That way others get to know that it works.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following search operators to fine-tune your queries in Twitter.

[image: twitter search operators]